# I can not render videos in kdenlive

Tags: 14.04, video-editor, kdenlive

I have a HDV NTSC 1080 60i project.

But when I try to render it, the program says :

```
[aac @ 0x7fec25bea380] Input buffer exhausted before END element found
```

I try to change: the file directory and the file type but many times, but nothing works.

Until now I render videos in kdenlive perfectly, any idea ?

I use latest version of kdenlive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solutions, the problem was, that I hat a corrupted PNG, so the program could not render the file.